# Currently supported APN gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

I am currently implementing APN (Apple Push Notifications) functionality in my Rails application.
Can you please suggest me a gem, which:

- keeps persistant connection
- can check apple feedbacks (for failed notifications)
- is well documented
- is supported

Closest I found for that was [apn_sender](https://github.com/arthurnn/apn_sender). Is there any better option? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used rapns for the same purpose with Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0. It's pretty cool.

```
gem 'rapns', :github => 'ileitch/rapns'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did a little looksie on RubyToolbox:

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=apple+push+notifications

https://github.com/nomad/houston 
13k downloads on Rubygems

https://github.com/grocer/grocer
37k downloads on Rubygems

Both seem to have fairly active development (commits in the last month)